# C# Encryption code ported to Java

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to convert the following code from C# to Java, but I get different result values of keys. Here are my codes:

**C#:**

```
        plainText = "Hello World";
        passPhrase = "IhDyHz6bgQyS0Ff1/1s=";
        saltValue = "0A0Qvv09OXd3GsYHVrA=";
        hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
        passwordIterations = 3;
        initVector = "GjrlRZ6INgNckBqv";
        keySize = 256;

        byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
        byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
                                                        passPhrase,
                                                        saltValueBytes,
                                                        hashAlgorithm,
                                                        passwordIterations);

        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
```

**Java**

```
        byte[] password = PassPhrase.getBytes("ASCII");
        byte[] salt = PKCS5S1ParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToBytes(SaltValue.toCharArray());

        PKCS5S1ParametersGenerator generator = new PasswordDeriveBytes(new SHA1Digest()); 
        generator.init(password, salt, PasswordIterations); 

        byte[] key = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(32)).getKey();
```

The issue is that I get different keys even with the same parameters provided on both codes: (only the first 4 bytes match)

**NOTE:** *this values had been converted to Base64:*

**C#:** GWR/loJAuuiPvP0cuGGCVXErz16HjOZ7yQkCCHfBux4=
**Java:** GWR/4oCT

If I keep playing with the number provided to generateDerivedParameters(32), it only gives me more bytes but still doesn't match the result at .Net.

I can't change the .Net code, so please any suggestion must be done at Java side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generateDerivedParameters` method says: "keySize the size of the key we want (in bits)". So you have to use `generateDerivedParameters(32 * 8)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but still not matching the C# key, this is the result: GWR/4oCT4oCaQMK6w6jvv73CvMO9HMK4YeKAmlVxK8OPXuKAocWSw6Z7w4kJAgh3w4HCux4=

Comment: Looks like different standard (sic!) of Base64 is used different alphabet. Could you compare bytes, the binary values to verify if it's the same?

Comment: OMG you're totally right, even though I've tested a lot the Base64 Java method conversion against its simil in C#, this time I've been foolish by this, looking at the bytes, they are actually the same.